# JQuery Passing value to a function with colon

Tags: jquery, function

I'm trying to learn JQuery and I stumble upon this script in one of the plugins in the repository that is similar to this.

```
var DOMChange = {

    textchange: function(eID) {
        $('document').ready(function() {
            $('eID').text("test3");
        });
    }
}

DOMChange.textchange('p');
```

I can't seem to get this working. Is there something missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: But, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Should that be `$(document).ready(...` -- without the quotes around `document`?  If that's not it, then you're going to have to give us more info about the problem.

Comment: we need more info. the posted code doesn't seem related to your topic question...

Comment: I just want to change the value in the P elements as stated in the code. Of course I try $('p').text("test3") and it works. I'm just looking for ways on writing jquery codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var DOMChange = {

    textchange: function(eID) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(eID).text("test3");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. If it would be okay, can anyone tell me about the colon in "textchange:" and what other uses it has?

Comment: In your code, the `DOMChange = {}` declares it as an object.  `textchange: function() {}` declares a property in that object named `textchange` whose value is the function you declare.  You can have as many properties as you want on an object.  The syntax for property definition is `propertyName: value` with the colon between propertyName and value.  If you had multiple properties defined, you would separate them with commas.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to find the answer in google. Can't find a definite answer. How about this one, is this possible >> $(document).ready(
 
 var DOME = {
 
 ChangeText: function(DE) {
  $(DE).text("D");
 }
 
 
 }
 
 DOME.ChangeText("#SideMenu li")
);

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the previous response your problem is in constructing the jQuery objects, you wrapped eID in quotes. $('eID') - syntactically at least - is trying to find all elements of type 'eID' ... which doesn't exist. $(eID) will take the value/argument you are passing to textchange. You're doing the same with $('document') - should be $(document)

I'll add that $(eID) will only work if eID is dom element/object or element type. If eID is a string representing the ID of an element, you'll need to make your selection something like this: $('#' + eID)